# Button click will not call javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have been trying to follow the example here to add a dynamic field that is created upon a button click [example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove) and have been unable to get it to work.

Here is my javascript file, which I am storing in my static file directory(other static files load fine, filename is 'recipeadd.js'):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var next = 1;
$("#b1").click(function(e){
    alert("Hi");
    e.preventDefault();
    var addto = "#field" + next;
    var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
    next = next + 1;
    var newIn = '<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '" type="text">';
    var newInput = $(newIn);
    var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-        danger remove-me" >-</button></div><div id="field">';
    var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
    $(addto).after(newInput);
    $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
    $("#field" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
    $("#count").val(next);

        $("#remove").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
            var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
            $(this).remove();
            $(fieldID).remove();
        });
    });
    });
```

Here is what's in my html header, loading both the js and associated css file:

```
   <!--CSS code for recipeadd-->
   <link href="{% static 'recipes/css/recipeadd.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
   <!--JS code for reccipeadd-->
   <script src="{% static 'recipes/js/recipeadd.js' %}"></script>
```

Finally, here is the container that contains button 'b1', which I'm trying to have execute the javascript:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    <!--div class="col-xs-4"-->
    <label for="recipeName">Recipe Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipeName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
        <label class="control-label" for="field1">Ingredients</label>
        <div class="controls" id="profs">
            <form class="input-append">
                <div id="field"><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="field1" name="prof1" type="text" placeholder="Enter one ingredient per line" data-items="8"/><button id="b1" class="btn add-more" type="button">+</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="directions">Directions</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="directions"></textarea>
</div>
```

I am teaching myself web development and using the Django framework for this project.  Sincerely appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I am assuming you have jQuery on the page, your code is not showing a jQuery reference.

Now assuming that the code adds the elements, I see one issue with adding your click event. You give the remove button the id with a number: `id="remove' + (next - 1) + '"`

Now when you attach the event, you do not use a number: `$("#remove").click(`

So either you need to use a number OR better yet, you already have the button element referenced, use that.

```
removeButton.click( function(){ });
```

Comment: Well as I mentioned I am just learning.  I did not have a jQuery reference in my html file.  I assumed as long as I had the javascript file reference that was good enough.  I downloaded jQuery and added the following reference, working now - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well as I mentioned I am just learning.  I did not have a jQuery reference in my html file.  I assumed as long as I had the javascript file reference that was good enough.  I downloaded jQuery and added the following reference, working now - thank you!

```
<!--jQuery core code-->
<script src="{% static 'recipes/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js' %}"></script>
```